# Facing issue installing pug-php/pug-symfony on Symfony 2.8.26

Tags: php, composer-php, pug, symfony-2.8

I am facing an issue while installing pug-php/pug-symfony in Symfony 2.8.
I started with a fresh symfony installation and executed

> composer require pug-php/pug-symfony

All the dependencies were fetched and downloaded and tyhe composer.json also got updated, however in the step of autoloader.php generation, it comes up with this error. (below image)

[autoload.php issue when installing pug on symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bof1Z.png)

To debug the issue, i tried executing

> composer dump-autoload -o

and the same error pops up again.

Next, I tried something cheeky and created a new blank autoload.php file in the Symfony project directory root, and again executed composer update and composer dump-autoload, however, this time am getting this,

[composer update issue (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZeNs.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong currently it is stating that there is no `autoload.php` file in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\demoSymfony\autoload.php`. There should be a `vendor` directory where the autoload.php file is found. Can you update your question with the current Repository structure/hierarchy? That will probably give us more info to help you.

Straight from their docs: `For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Hi,
I have updated the issue over at github, please follow the issue here @ 

[pug-php/pug-symfony](https://github.com/pug-php/pug-symfony/issues/15)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this issue, you should now be able to install it with no such problem by following the README install process:
https://github.com/pug-php/pug-symfony#pug-symfony